# Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client - Opens IE

Tags: windows-7, cisco-vpn-client

I don't know why this started happening - but as of recently when I log on to my work VPN via the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client an instance of Internet Explorer is opened up once the log on is complete.

Are there are any workarounds to stop this or options to turn this off?

I am using:
v2.4.1012 Client
Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this problem, it eventually went away for me (my guess is our OPs guys changed something on the VPN setup side). However, for a short while, **note:  BIG HACK** was modify the internet explorer executable in my System32 folder (I don't use IE anyways, so no big loss for me). I just changed the file name extension and lo and behold, no more problem :P

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the fact that it launches the client VPN access url through which it connects. Once the connection is established, it launches success page of your client URL.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you have it set to auto start a program. Have you checked under `Options -> App Launcher`?

Just uncheck the enable box if there is a link pointed to your IE, this should stop that if this is the case.